# SFHFKeychainUtils persistance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.5

I am using `SFHFKeychainUtils` for storing data in `keychain`.

My question is - once I delete the application from the background, does the data *stay* within the `SFHFKeychainUtils`? And if so, for how long?

Any guidance or reference would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i am not working with this `wrapper class` but if this classes deal with `keychain` then it will be defiantly save the credential after delete application form BG even from device and re-install app. you can get that credential.

For more information about `keychain services` please refer [**this**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html) apple doc.

Apple also provide [**sample code**.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_h.html)